# Chef Cookbooks: Installing Jenkins plugin with chef failing

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to setup a Jenkins server using one of the Chef cookbooks from the supermarket. Unfortunately it is failing with the below error. The plugin recipe requires for the Global security configuration - "Enable CLI with remoting" to be enabled. Can anybody help me to enable it from a Chef recipe so that 
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -remoting
installs the plugin.

Thanks

Here is the error log

```
java.io.IOException: No X-Jenkins-CLI2-Port among [X-Jenkins, null, Server, X-Content-Type-Options, X-You-Are-In-Group-Disabled, X-Hudson, X-Permission-Implied-By, Date, X-Jenkins-Session, X-You-Are-Authenticated-As, X-Required-Permission, Set-Cookie, Expires, Content-Length, Content-Type]
            at hudson.cli.CLI.getCliTcpPort(CLI.java:311)
            at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:137)
            at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:82)
            at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:615)
            at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:426)
            Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/cli?remoting=true                                                                     
                    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)                                                                                           
                    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)                                                                                            
                    at hudson.cli.FullDuplexHttpStream.<init>(FullDuplexHttpStream.java:101)
                    at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaHttp(CLI.java:163)
                    at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:141)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation, `remoting` option is disabled by default. you can enable it by going to `Configure Global Security`. I don't think by programatically we can't enable it. For more details use this official link. [Remoting Connection Mode | official Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#remoting-connection-mode)

This is the solution they are providing for your problem. Hope this helps.

> Go to Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security and choose "Fixed" or "Random" under TCP port for JNLP agents.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the remoting option by writing a bit of Groovy that gets run when Jenkins starts, but a better option is to configure the proper authentication and use the ssh or http methods.

https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins#authentication

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51106793/3794873